# Form: emptytext - display text in empty row at the bottom of a dataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I use CanUserAddRows property in a Windows Forms datagrid to let the user add rows to a grid that is bound to a database table. I would like to show a text on the first column of that empty row to indicate the user has to fill it that row to create a new row. When the user clicks or enters that row that text should disappear. How can i do that ?

Comment: is this property available in WinForms DataGrid !?

Comment: in the designer it is called AllowUserToAddRows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

```
private void dgvKlanten2_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e) {
      int rows = ds1.Tables["Klanten"].Rows.Count;
      //when loading
      if (e.RowIndex == rows  - 1) {
        dgvKlanten2.Rows[e.RowIndex+1].Cells[2].Value = "add a record here";
        dgvKlanten2.Rows[e.RowIndex+1].Cells[2].Style.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
      }

      //when adding a new row
      if (e.RowIndex > rows ) {
        dgvKlanten2.Rows[rows].Cells[1].Value = getNieuwKlantNummer();
        dgvKlanten2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value = "add a record here";
        dgvKlanten2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Style.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
        dgvKlanten2.Rows[e.RowIndex-1].Cells[2].Style.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        dgvKlanten2.Rows[e.RowIndex-1].Cells[2].Value = String.Empty;
      }
    }
```